# how to add link in blueimp gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blueimp

I'm trying to add a delete link under my list of images that will delete the selected image from the gallery

The issue I’m having is that whenever the delete button is clicked it opens the gallery of images.

HTML

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>

<div id="links">
<a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana">
    <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
</a>
<a href="image/delete/id" title="Delete">Delete></a>

<a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Apple">
    <img src="images/thumbnails/apple.jpg" alt="Apple">
</a>
<a href="image/delete/id" title="Delete">Delete></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
event = event || window.event;
var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
    link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
    options = {index: link, event: event},
    links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
blueimp.Gallery(links, options); };
```

Comment: Hi, did you solved this? I'm having the same problem and I don't know how I can fix it.